# Filter null byte in request

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I am using htmlpurifier library for sanitizing my incoming parameters. But it is not filtering null bytes (for e.g. %00). Am I missing something or the library does not support it? Will I be required to use a reg-ex? Thanks for any answers.

**Edit:**

I am using htmlpurifier with config options

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core', 'Encoding', "UTF-8");
$config->set('Cache', 'SerializerPath', "/webdirs/htmlpurify");
```

For the test string

```
';</script><%00script>alert(845122)</script>
```

I get the output

```
';<%00script>alert(845122)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown by HTMLPurifier/EncoderTest.php and HTMLPurifierTest.php, HTML Purifier does clean out null bytes:

```
    $this->assertPurification("Null byte\0", "Null byte");
```

and

```
    $this->assertCleanUTF8("null byte: \0", 'null byte: ');
```

Maybe you should post some code?

Edit: Your edit is slightly misleading; the actual output code is:

```
';&amp;lt;%00script&amp;gt;alert(845122)
```

which is just a string of plain text and perfectly safe. Percent-signs do not have special meaning in HTML.

If you would like to place a string in a URL, use urlencode().

Comment: Commander - thanks for the reply. I have added some code, but not sure if it is enough. Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: the problem is that i cannot use html special chars as output from htmlpurifier. so i run a html_entity_decode on top of it. Now this value causes the issue. Is their any way to tell htmlpurifier to remove the script tag even when there is a %00 in between??

Comment: Uh, come again? Why can't you use html special chars as output from HTML Puriifer? (running html_entity_decode is the WRONG WRONG way to do things, and assuredly leads to security vulnerabilities)

Comment: i cant use html special chars as output since the application i am working on has a session value which is getting encoded resulting in me logging of (when the value is encoded). I had a feeling that html_entity_decode is wrong, but can you give me any concrete example where it would affect? Thanks again for the time and explanation.

Comment: &amp;amp;lt;script&amp;amp;gt; becomes &amp;lt;script&amp;gt; becomes &lt;script&gt; becomes <script>.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like HTML Purifier is filtering this string correctly, IF it appears within Javascript code.

In Javascript, you want to filter out any occurences of a closing tag, such as `</script>` even when it appears within a Javascript string literal.  Otherwise, injecting `</script>` into a string value can bypass some non-careful filters and break out of the Javascript string and into arbitrary HTML.  HTML Purifier seems to have correctly filtered this by removing that "tag".

There is no harm having `<%00script>` in a literal string within Javascript, IF that is indeed the context in which it appears.

Note also that `%00` is not actually a null byte or PHP, or in HTML, or a Javascript script.  It is a percent sign followed by two zeroes.  However, in a URL `%00` might indeed be interpreted as a null byte and therefore `%00` should be filtered out of URLs.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i understand that %00 needs oly to be filtered in URLs. Can you please add an example or link on how to add htmlpurifier on the javascript side? i have only been using it on the php side.